# What is the relationship between the Metering Office and the Electric Company?

Tags: uml, diagram, actor, relationships, use-case

Let me first show you my diagram...

[image]

The Metering Office, Metering Data Management System and the Energy Control Department are all departments of the Electric Company, but the Metering Office is the main actor, so to say. It does pretty much everything, excepting getting the money for the liquidation.

What relationship could I have between the Metering Office and the Electric Company to keep them in the same diagram?

Answer (score 1):

- Use cases should be ovals, connected to Actor(s) and to (Sub)system(s). Metering Office is not a person, so it should be shown as a rectangle. But a Metering Service Employee can be shown as a stick man.
- Subsystems can be shown as smaller rectangles inside larger ones, or by approximately same sizes rectangles, connected by "containment" relationship - line with small circle on the end of container, the circle has a cross inside.
- So, you can choose variant of containment connections or direct including. In the first case all agents will be inside a large rectangle, named Electric Company.